# Understanding Haskell postgresql connection function type error

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I am java programmer reading and learning haskell now. I am trying write a simple program to connect (and disconnect) to postgres database using HDBC postgres driver. For simplicity i don't have any other logic in it.

It is throwing a function type error. I indented the code correct and if I remove disconnect then it works with the defined type.

Can some one shed some light on what i am missing defining the type for this function? i would apriciate your help.

thanks!

sample code:

```
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.PostgreSQL
import Database.HaskellDB
import Database.HaskellDB.HDBC.PostgreSQL

tryConnect :: Int  -> (Database -> IO Connection) -> ()   
tryConnect id =
   do
     c <- postgresqlConnect [("host","dbhost"),("dbname","db1"),("user","user1"),("password","test")]
     disconnect c
     return ()
```

I am getting the following error from GHCi

```
   Couldn't match expected type `(Database -> IO Connection) -> a'
       against inferred type `IO ()'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression: disconnect c
In the expression:
    do { c <- postgresqlConnect
                [("host", "dbhost"), ("dbname", "db1"), ....];
         disconnect c;
         return () }
In the definition of `insrt':
    insrt id
            = do { c <- postgresqlConnect [("host", "dbhost"), ....];
                   disconnect c;
                   return () }
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't provided enough arguments to `postgresqlConnect`. Its type signature is `[(String, String)] -> (Database -> m a) -> m a`, but you've only provided the first argument. Giving `postgresqlConnect` its second argument should solve the problem, and you'll be able to change the type declaration back to `Int -> IO ()`.

EDIT: The answer below is totally wrong. My bad.

<strike>Well, the type signature is `tryConnect :: Int -> (Database -> IO Connection) -> ()`. Generally this would indicate that the function takes an `Int` and a `(Database -> IO Connection)` and returns `()`, but the only parameter you've supplied in the function definition is `id`. Therefore, you actually have a function that takes an `Int` and returns a new function with the type signature `(Database -> IO Connection) -> ()`.</strike>

This would be fine, except that the body of the function does not match this signature. The `do` expression returns an `IO ()` value rather than the expected function, so you get an error because the compiler got a different return value than expected.

So, to conclude, it seems there's a parameter in the type signature that you haven't used in the actual function. Either remove that function from the type signature, or change the function to be `tryConnect id func = ...` rather than `tryConnect id = ...`.

Comment: thanks Jeffrey. Type is defined by me, not by the function. i was not clear on that earlier.  Initially i tried with this type,

Comment: tryConnect :: Int -> IO ().  This throws the following exception

Comment: my bad..comments are broken.     { Couldn't match expected type `IO ()'
           against inferred type `(Database -> m a) -> b'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        c <- postgresqlConnect
               [("host", "dbhost"), ("dbname", "db1"), ("user", "user1"),
                ("password", "test")]
    In the expression:
        do { c <- postgresqlConnect
                    [("host", "dbhost"), ("dbname", "db1"), ....];
             disconnect c;
             return () }
}

Comment: In the function you wrote in the question, try changing the `()` at the end to `IO ()` and see if that compiles.

Comment: I tried changing to IO () and still getting the error.  It is complaining about disconnect function. Here is the error: {Couldn't match expected type `(Database -> IO Connection) -> a'
           against inferred type `IO ()'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: disconnect c
}

Comment: Wow, I totally misread that error before. The problem is just that you didn't give `postgresqlConnect` enough arguments. The type signature is `[(String, String)] -> (Database -> m a) -> m a`, but you only provided the `[(String, String)]` argument. I'll submit another answer with the correct solution.

Comment: Ah! I overlooked postgresconnect function. thanks for pointing out. let me try this and post the result.